# Contact Form 7 - Checkbox customization / stylization

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm working on my site: http://cleaners.se/home/#kontakt

I have an issue, I want to style the checkboxes to look the same as other forms.
I want the checkbox to be exclusive, so you can choose just one checkbox. Is it also right way to put them next to each other? or is there any better way to do it?

I've already done this:

```css
.knapp + label {
}

label {
 display: inline;
}

.knapp {
 display: none;
}

.knapp + label {
 background-color: #2CACA9;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 top: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.knapp + label:active, .knapp:checked + label:active {
}

.knapp:checked + label {
 background-color: #2CACA9;
 border: 0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.knapp:checked + label:after {
 content: '\2716';
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: "montserrat";
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 left: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="telefon" class="knapp" /><label for="telefon"></label><input type="checkbox" id="e-post" class="knapp" /><label for="e-post"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to only select one of the checkboxes at a time.

Then you want to use a radio input

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_button" /> Yes
<br />
<input type="radio" name="radio_button" /> No
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I'm using the "standard" boxes in Contact Form 7 plugin, there is also an "exclusive" option for boxes. Is there any exclusive tag/code for the boxes?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "standard" and "exclusive" ?

Are you using the Contact From 7 Wordpress plugin?

In the form section you can any HTML / class' / id's you like

Comment: If you check the link to my website, you will understand what I mean :-) There are two kind of checkboxes on that website, one that is already customized and one that is original by contact form 7. Let me know if you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've been working on this for a while now. I've found that it can be needed to add JavaScript, and yes it works with jQuery 1.7, my question now for somebody that is better than me on javascript... is ther any way to make this script better? Have in mind it works only with jQuery 1.7 what I think..

```
<script>
    $('div .knapp').click(function() {
        checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
        $(this).parent('div').children('.knapp:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
        $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
    });
</script>
```